# Advice on how to structure my database according to 2 identifiers?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am building a database with Postgres.

Here is how I want to structure it (conceptually):

```
my_database = {  
    '1.0.0': {  
        'testA': result1,
        'testB': result2
    },  
    '2.0.0': {
        'testA': result3,
        'testB': result4
    }
}
```

To explain, I have a program that is versioned (e.g. '1.0.0'), and I have tests that I run on it (e.g. 'testA'), and those tests produce results (e.g. 'result1').

Now, the same version and same test will always produce the same result, so I will want to be checking my database to see if "version 1.0.0 and testB" already has an entry. If so, no need to store any duplicate results.

I am thinking there must be a way to have some sort of many-to-many relationship between tests and versions, where every version has a bunch of tests entered, and each test is perhaps used by many versions.

I am pretty new to database design and am wondering how to set this up to be quick and save space, assuming I have thousands of unique versions, each with thousands of tests (many shared tests across versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one table for the versions, one for the tests and a third one for the results. The latter table has foreign key references to the other two, and its primary key is composed of these two foreign key fields.